# Jquery. Apply function to each div individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm relatively new Jquery. And JS as a whole.
I've tasked myself with building what is in effect a basic framework builder.

I have a small piece of Jquery which counts the number of child divs (columns) within a container and then sets the width of the columns depending on how many children are present.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
function builder(){
var contCount = $('div.container').children().length;

if (contCount == 1) {
    $('div.container').children().css('width', '100%');
}
else if (contCount == 2) {
    $('div.container').children().css('width', '50%');
}
else if (contCount == 3) {
    $('div.container').children().css('width', '33.33%');
}
else if (contCount == 4) {
    $('div.container').children().css('width', '25%');
}
}
$(document).ready(builder);
```

**The problem:**
The above works when I have one container, but if I have the multiple containers that I want, it breaks. I know why it breaks, but not how to fix it.

**The question:**
Is there a way in Jquery/JS that I can apply the function to multiple container classes individually?

Thank you!

Neil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery

```
function builder(){
    $('div.container').each(function(){
        var $children = $(this).children();
        var contCount = $children.length;

        if (contCount == 1) {
            $children.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else if (contCount == 2) {  
            $children.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else if (contCount == 3) {
            $children.css('background-color', 'green');
        }
        else if (contCount == 4) {
            $children.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(builder);
```

Comment: sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function builder(){
$('div.container').each(function(){
  
  var contCount = $(this).children().length;

  if (contCount == 1) {
      $(this).children().css('width', '100%');
  }
  else if (contCount == 2) {
      $(this).children().css('width', '50%');
  }
  else if (contCount == 3) {
      $(this).children().css('width', '33.33%');
  }
  else if (contCount == 4) {
      $(this).children().css('width', '25%');
  }
 
});
}
$(document).ready(builder);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>    
    <div  class="col">test</div>    
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>    
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>    
</div>
```

Try this using each function you can achieve it !

Answer (score 0):

the line `var contCount = $('div.container').children().length;` counts the childs of **all** `'div.container'` selector matched elements, you want to isolate the containers and ask each one of containers how many childs he have.

```
function builder(){
    $('div.container').each(function() {
        var $children = $(this).children();
        var contCount = $children.length;

        if (contCount == 1) {
            $children.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else if (contCount == 2) {  
            $children.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else if (contCount == 3) {
            $children.css('background-color', 'green');
        }
        else if (contCount == 4) {
            $children.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry. accidentally replaced all. thanks for restoring it back :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This I think this should be work

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.fn.equalWidth = function(){              
                jQuery(this).each(function() {                  
                    var findLenght = jQuery(this).find('.col').length,
                        width = 100/findLenght;
                    jQuery(this).find('.col').css({'width': width+'%'});
                });             
        }
        jQuery('.container').equalWidth();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to accomplish can be achieved much simpler with css/flexbox
see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

For example:

CSS:

```
.container
{   
    display: flex;
}

.col
{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
  </div>
```

Actually, using js instead of CSS to manipulate styles is a malpractice leading to poor code and difficult to remove problems.

Answer (score 0):

Lets explain why you don't get your expected output.Its always important to understand the problem from the deep. Its help you to solve other problems like it.

I like use your code reference.

Your HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
</div>
```

Your JS Code:

```
function builder(){
    var contCount = $('div.container').children().length;

    if (contCount == 1) {
        $('div.container').children().css('width', '100%');
    }
    else if (contCount == 2) {
        $('div.container').children().css('width', '50%');
    }
    else if (contCount == 3) {
        $('div.container').children().css('width', '33.33%');
    }
    else if (contCount == 4) {
        $('div.container').children().css('width', '25%');
    }
}
$(document).ready(builder);
```

Lets digging in.

First of all you have a parent class `.container`. Its have 4 children.

In this situation your code is generate the result absolutely fine,because parent is only one. The problem is commit when its have multiple parent.

Now you can ask me why?

Ok, Lets explain.
`$(document).ready(builder);` In this line you invoke the `builder` function. When you invoked it first execute `var contCount = $('div.container').children().length;` line.

The result is obviously `4`. because the number of children is `4`.

Suppose you have two `.container` class.Each container different number of children.

```
<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
</div>
```

In this situation when your `builder` function is invoked, then `contCount` variable result will be 2.

Confused!!

Suppose:

```
var foo = 4;
var foo = 2;

console.log(foo) // 2
```

Same thing is happened here. The number of first `.container` class child is 4 and second `.container` class child is 2.
 So `contCount` will be 2. This is main problem.

I thing you debug it now. But I want share my solve of this problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
    <div  class="col">test</div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
const builder = function(){
$('div.container').each(function(index,item){
const length = $(item).children('.col').length;
const gridNumber = 100/length;

if(length > 0) {
    $(item).children().css('width', `${gridNumber}%`);
}

})

}


$(document).ready(builder);
```